# Antd dropdown hides options when a certain amount of options is reached

Tags: reactjs, antd, ui-design

So i have an antd select

```
<Select >
    <Option value="option1">Option 1</Option>
    <Option value="option2">Option 2</Option>
    <Option value="option3">Option 3</Option>
    <Option value="option4">Option 4</Option>
    <Option value="option5">Option 5</Option>
    <Option value="option6">Option 6</Option>
    <Option value="option7">Option 7</Option>
    <Option value="option8">Option 8</Option>
    <Option value="option9">Option 9</Option>
    <Option value="option10">Option 10</Option>
</Select>
```

Works fine

[image]

when i add another option scrollbar shows and options become hidden

```
<Select >
    <Option value="option1">Option 1</Option>
    <Option value="option2">Option 2</Option>
    <Option value="option3">Option 3</Option>
    <Option value="option4">Option 4</Option>
    <Option value="option5">Option 5</Option>
    <Option value="option6">Option 6</Option>
    <Option value="option7">Option 7</Option>
    <Option value="option8">Option 8</Option>
    <Option value="option9">Option 9</Option>
    <Option value="option10">Option 10</Option>
    <Option value="option11">Option 11</Option>
</Select>
```

[image]

I have tried setting maxHeight but not sure what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change **dropdownStyle** props of the **Select** component. Please see the code below

```
<Select dropdownStyle={{width: 'max-content'}}>
    <Option value="option1">Option 1</Option>
    <Option value="option2">Option 2</Option>
    <Option value="option3">Option 3</Option>
    <Option value="option4">Option 4</Option>
    <Option value="option5">Option 5</Option>
    <Option value="option6">Option 6</Option>
    <Option value="option7">Option 7</Option>
    <Option value="option8">Option 8</Option>
    <Option value="option9">Option 9</Option>
    <Option value="option10">Option 10</Option>
    <Option value="option11">Option 11</Option>
</Select>
```